# Feature extraction in images and image processing

Tags: c++, image-processing

In my project I should do face detection.I succeeded in it but now I want to do feature extraction in it. So is there any algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Feature extraction can mean a lot of different things.  You would have to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you using a toolkit? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) you have a tutorial on feature detection using OpenCV. There are lots of Feature Detection algorithms (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28computer_vision%29)). The OpenCV tutorial shows you an example using SURF features. The main part of the example is this:

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
```

In `keypoints_1`you have the points that are more relevant. Then I am sure you will need to describe a patch around the point.
I suggest to follow [this tutorial](http://morf.lv/modules.php?name=tutorials&lasit=2) on doing so. The main part of the code is this:

```
//vector of keypoints  
vector< cv::KeyPoint > keypointsS; //keypoints for scene
//Descriptor matrices
Mat descriptors_scene;

SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
extractor.compute( sceneMat, keypointsS, descriptors_scene );
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user3218797 I edited the answer. Hope it helps